# IP to Country in Excel

Tags: excel, geolocation, location, ip

I have a column full of IP's and want to automatically get the country of those IP's in the column next to it.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible using plain Excel.  You will need to make one or more REST calls in which you pass in your IP address to ultimately obtain a country.  This seems, at first glance, to be possible using VBA.  You could also use a tool like `R` to handle this problem.

Here is a link to a free IP lookup service which you can try: http://freegeoip.net/?q=118.189.52.134

It may even return the country associated with the IP address.  If it only returns the latitude and longitude, then you can make a second call to the [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get a country.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any free approach. For commercial, you can install additional component to run the IP geolocation query in MS Excel desktop.

https://www.ip2location.com/free/excel-addin

This does not work in Office 365.